# Возможен ли такой ответ?

Tags: синтаксис

К примеру, у нас есть диалог (см. ниже). Является ли вторая реплика корректной с точки зрения грамматики? Если да, то что это? Номинативное предложение?

```
Где расположены сервера? - Нью-Джерси.
```

Если бы всё было так, то вопрос бы у меня даже не появился. Это было бы неполное предложение.

```
Где расположены сервера? - В Нью-Джерси.
```

Answer (score 3):

Такой ответ (с отбрасыванием предлога) допустим в условиях плохой слышимости или профессиональной спешки, когда нужно передать информативную единицу. В обычной речи он тоже будет понятным, но грамматически это не ответ на поставленный вопрос, а небрежная и потому не совсем вежливая реплика (вас как бы "не удостаивают" предлогом).

Comment: Верно подмечено! Не удостаивают, поэтому какой-то осадок возникает.

Comment: Александр, грамматически ясно, что ответ неверный. Но вот насчет невежливости Вы больно преувеличиваете. Иначе любую ошибку надо рассматривать как невежливость.

Comment: В данном случае название не склоняется, поэтому ответ выглядит не как ошибка, а как намеренное упрощение до именительного падежа, что может восприниматься как невежливость: "я вам назвал то, где это, а вы уж сами к контексту присобачивайте". Ошибка выглядит ошибкой, если в предложном падеже склоняемого существительного отбрасывают предлог: - Где будет? - Москве (на той неделе был похожий вопрос в англоязычной части форума).